# Are (brain) imaging signal processing questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

So as an example, [here 's a brain imaging signal processing question on CogSci](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/18466/spm5-contrast-vectors-too-long-when-applied-to-a-new-spm-mat-file). Although this question is well-prepared and on topic there, it will very likely never receive an answer.

This type of question also appears sometimes at Bio.SE.

Now I'd like to migrate the linked question, and perhaps others too if applicable.

Are signal processing questions on imaging on topic and welcomed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tldr: At present, such questions are probably less likely to get answered here than where they are.

I would have thought you'd have more cog. neuro. folks on CogSci than we would here (I'm one of the few neuroscientists here). While I think one could argue that biological image and signal processing questions fall under the purview of bioinformatics, in practice I don't foresee anyone on the site currently being familiar enough with the topics to offer any real help. Most of the time bioinfo is an umbrella term for NGS, microarray, proteomics and (sometimes) structure. So while I don't personally think such posts are strictly off-topic, I also don't think it's worth migrating them. I hope for this to change in the future as the site's user-base increases.

Update: See also [this meta question](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/computational-biology-but-not-gene-sequences) from earlier. Maybe if we make this site a hub for such questions we can encourage those communities to join. I would certainly welcome that.

Comment: Thanks I'll leave them where they are then. Cheers.

Comment: Bioinformatics is just as much things like comparative genomics, phylogenetics etc. I'm always surprised when I encounter people who think of it as being essentially the four things you mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, I'm all for encouraging the broader field to participate. We NGS folks just overwhelm everyone else with our shear numbers.